# How to change Toolbar and BottomNavigationBar theme in activity

Tags: android, kotlin, material-components-android

> So, I tried creating bottom navigation bar and navigation drawer in 1
> activity (i used new activity drawer template and combine it with the
> Bottom Navigation View tag I got from bottom navigation activity). I
> want to change the theme for both the toolbar and bottom navigation
> drawer on run time ( so I thought about using setTheme on activity)
> but the setTheme does not work (the color does not change)
> I tried to set the theme on each attribute on XML (on AppBarLayout and
> BottomNavigationView container tag) and it does work. But when I tried
> via programmatically, I set activity on their context, but it does
> nothing
>
> contain_main_container.xml

```xml
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/AppNightTheme"
    tools:context=".MainContainerActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_nav_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        app:itemBackground="?colorPrimary"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/nav_item_color"
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/nav_item_color"
        android:background="?colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

> app_bar_main_container.xml

```xml
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainContainerActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar_toolbar"
        android:theme="@style/AppNightTheme"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main_container"/>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

> the step above does work, but it needs me to set the theme manually at
> the start and cannot change at run time. I did some research and some
> say that just changing the theme on parent does change everything on
> their children, but mine does not work.
>
> what I have tried on MainContainerActivity.kt

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        sharedPreferences  = getSharedPreferences("preferences", 0)
        if(sharedPreferences.getBoolean("DayTheme",true)){
            setTheme(R.style.AppDayTheme)
        }
        else{
            setTheme(R.style.AppNightTheme)
        }
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_container)
        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
        toolbar.title = ""
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)



        homeFragment = HomeFragment()
        discoverFragment = DiscoverFragment()
        notificationFragment = NotificationFragment()
        settingFragment = SettingFragment()

        if(savedInstanceState != null){
            when(savedInstanceState.getInt("last_fragment")){
                R.id.navigation_discover -> {
                    val fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, discoverFragment)
                    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null)
                    fragmentTransaction.commit()
                }
                R.id.navigation_home -> {
                    val fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, homeFragment)
                    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null)
                    fragmentTransaction.commit()
                }
                R.id.navigation_favorites -> {
                }
                R.id.navigation_notifications -> {
                    val fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()

                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, notificationFragment)
                    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null)
                    fragmentTransaction.commit()
                }

                R.id.navigation_settings -> {
                    val fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, settingFragment)
                    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null)
                    fragmentTransaction.commit()
                }
                else -> false
            }
        }
        else{
            val fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            val homeFragment = HomeFragment()
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container,homeFragment)
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null)
            fragmentTransaction.commit()
        }

        val bottomNav : BottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_nav_view)
        bottomNav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(onNavigationItemSelectedListener)

        val drawerLayout: DrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)
        val navView: NavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)
        val toggle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close
        )
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle)
        toggle.syncState()

        navView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, Hello and welcome to stackoverflow!

As for the question, I'm pretty sure you need to restart your activity after you change your theme. For Api 11 and beyond:

```
Activity.recreate()
```

For Api before 11:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
finish();
startActivity(intent);
```

Hope I was helpful!

**Edit**
You can't change ToolBar and BottomNavigationView themes at runtime. You can only change the background color and the title color.
For the toolbar,

```
toolbar.setBackgroundColor(newColor); 
toolbar.setTitleTextColor(titleColor);
```

For the BottomNavigationView,

```
navigation.setBackgroundColor();
navigation.setItemTextColor();
```

Comment: yea bro i done that already, for the fragment inside, the color is already changed, but for the toolbar and the bottom nav, it does not change

Comment: I just researched a little and analysed your code better. You can't change toolbar and BottomNavigationView programmatically. The code you showed is changing the context theme, not the "container" or the ToolBar themes. That said, you are doing "setTheme" to the same activity 3 consecutive times. You can only change the background color and the title color at runtime

Answer (score 0):

To set programmatically in activity you have to set it before  setContentView().but if you want to change it after activity started then you have to recreate or relaunch activity.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setTheme(R.style.AppDayTheme); // (for Custom theme)
    setContentView(R.layout.your_activity);
}
```

Comment: yeah bro, the fragment inside changed according to the theme, but the color on bottom nav and toolbar does not change

Comment: colorPrimary in you style will set as a toolbar and bottomnavigationbar color

Answer (score 0):

you can use attribute tag in attrs.xml to use in color tag. remember if you are having two themes that must be default and secondary thus you must have to declare two color tags using same attribute tag 
like this

**step 1: define attribute tag**

```
<attr name="toolbarcolor" format="color"></attr>
```

use attribute tag  to define two color selection

**step 2: define colors names**

```
 <color name="toolbarcolordefualt">#F36C63</color>
<color name="toolbarcolorsecondary">#4CAF50</color>
```

**step 3: define style**

```
 <style name="AppTheme.Default" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
   <item name="toolbarcolor">@color/toolbarcolordefualt</item>
 </style>  

 <style name="AppTheme.secondary" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
  <item name="toolbarcolor">@color/toolbarcolorsecondary</item>
```

**use that attribute to your toolbar**

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:background="?attr/toolbarcolor"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"/>
```

rest things is just you have to maintain which theme needs to be appear using sharedpreference in **settheme()** function

**And for bottomnavigationbar you can use it according to your sharedpreference using if else condition**

```
getWindow().setNavigationBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.anycolor));
```